# Is the name of the app subjected to legal terms or only the company's name?

Tags: android, ios, iphone

I was at first wondering if the name of the application should be unique on the app stores and then I ran across an answer that says that it is no longer the case on.

I am confused to how true is this? Does this mean that the company's domain in the store should be unique and I am free to call my app whatever I want even if the name is already there on the store but of different functionality?

Thank you!

Comment: I believe you can name your app whatever you want, i've seen apps sharing the same name, domain should be Unique, so you can't have two apps sharing name and domain, but i'm not 100% sure

Answer (score 0):

As for playstore you need a unique domain name to separate your app from other apps with same name. The leagal term is another thing. If for example try to use a copyright name for your app (ex. Coca-Cola) you ll not have problems with Google play, but with Coca Cola.

So, you can name your app whatever you want if you have a unique domain name to be uploaded in Google Play.

To be leagal you need a name that dont break copyright laws.